# Не компилируется программа с использованием JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Я тут прохожу один видеокурс и там для работы с XML используется JAXB. Как я понимаю, его удалили из стандартной SE, поэтому в настройках проекта в идее во вкладке modules я подгрузил джарник с jaxb-api. Все импорты прописались, но при компиляции ничего не работает, вылезает куча ошибок. Ок, добавил module-info, часть пакетов подкрасилась красным. Добавил require'ы, вроде идея ни на что не жалуется. Запускаю на компиляцию, чтобы проверить как программа отработает тестовые данные и получаю такое сообщение:
"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.activation not found, required by java.xml.bind".
Итогом работы программы должен создаться один файл, его нет. Не подскажите, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: [Исчерпывающий ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) на ваш вопрос=)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, это читал. Вот думаю через мавен попробовать, но сначала нужно его освоить=)

Comment: Думаю этого руководства будет достаточно для начала изучения https://proselyte.net/tutorials/maven/

Comment: Это очень крутой гайд! Спасибо!